# Layout not adjusting to all screen size

Tags: android, layout, screen

I have created an android application. It is according screen size 320*480. but when i uses different device with different screen size designs not so proper as required. how can i resolve this issue.please suggest how to create design that fits on all screen size.
 my current layout is:-

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bg"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="2.0" >

<include
    android:id="@+id/mainScreenHeader"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.4"
    layout="@layout/main_screen_header" />

<include
    android:id="@+id/mainScreenListHeader"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.1"
    layout="@layout/main_screen_list_header" >
</include>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1.0"
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="false" />

<include
    android:id="@+id/mainScreenFilterClient"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.2"
    layout="@layout/main_screen_filter_client" >
</include>

<include
    android:id="@+id/footer"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.2"


    layout="@layout/footer" >
</include>
```

Comment: please mention your current layout

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the challenges of developing on Android.  There are many different android devices with many different display characteristics.  The dev guide gives a good overview of this topic:

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Probably what you will want to do, is to provide different layouts for different screens.  The above link discusses that approach.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, [this link](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) will help in understanding how to support multiple screed sizes.

It is preferable to add folders to resources folder in Android project to support many resolutions such as:

layout-large

layout-small

layout-xlarge

layout-normal-port-xhdpi-1280x800